# How to do mapping of 3d arrays

Tags: python, numpy, mapping

I have a numpy array of shape (20,512,512).
I want to get  a list of arrays of length 20 matching the array at points (:,100,100) (:,105,100), (:,110,100)
and so on.
I understand i need to use map for it, but how do I do it exactly?

many thanks
Yuval

Comment: What do you mean by matching the array? Your array cannot be reshaped into an array of shape (x, 100,100)

Comment: Why `map`?  Don't confuse the `map` function (alternative list comprehension), `mapping` such as a `dict`, and `numy` indexing.

Comment: I mean something like use map = [[True, False, False, False....],[False, True, true...]] and get a sequences of length 20, at the points of True in this 2D array in A[map].

Comment: We usably call that a boolean mask, though the terminology isn't fixed.

Answer (score 0):

you could achieve this by index slicing.

here's an example for a 1D array.

```
a = np.arange(200)
a[100::5]                           # from index 100 to end with increments of 5

>>> array([100, 105, 110, 115, 120, 125, 130, 135, 140, 145, 150, 155, 160,
           165, 170, 175, 180, 185, 190, 195])
```

for your case

```
shape = [20,512,512]
arr   = np.random.randint(0, 100, shape)     # creating an array with the required shape
```

```
arr[:, 100::5, 100]                          # index slicing

>>> array([[88, 74, 45, ..., 72, 33, 63],
           [88, 26, 53, ..., 47, 78, 16],
           [26, 54, 85, ..., 89, 81, 66],
           ...,
           [76,  1, 11, ...,  3, 74,  7],
           [93, 34, 84, ..., 84, 73, 79],
           [77, 10, 61, ...,  4, 21, 19]])
```

```
arr[:, 100::5, 100].shape

>>> (20, 83)
```